# Dynamic content without page refresh and without AJAX? e.g. use meta data?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I read something a while ago (but have lost the source) that explained how it was possible (with PHP) to transfer data(content) via things such as cookies, header fields, etc...

The PHP script would write the content to lets say cookies, and then the browser would read from the cookie and display the content using javascript. In this way you could deliver content without making another request to the webserver and without refreshing the page.

Is that possible? If so what are the options, and what are the limitations? (e.g. default time-out is 30 seconds on a php script...).

Comment: Cookies are part of the HTTP request header that is sent before the page content, so updating that dynamically won't work without a new request to the server. Also, cookies are limited to 4096 bytes (I believe).

Comment: How is this different from attaching data to HTML itself (with `data` attributes, for example)? Basically, the only difference between it and headers' stuff is that the former is visible via 'View Source' command; on the other hand, pretty much every browser this day can show Request/Response headers as well.

Comment: Im trying to avoid making server requests...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to do something like this because it massively increases page load times. Although it is possible to do such things.

I wouldn't use cookies, though. If I had to build a structure like that, I would load different pages in DIVs with IDs and set their CSS display to none by default and to "load" a different page, I would simply set the previous' pages DIV to display: none and the newly loaded DIV to display: block.

But I guess there are many solutions to this problem.

Comment: can you suggest a solution that avoids server requests?

Comment: This DOES avoid server requests. You load one page that contains ALL the content you could ever need at once, only that it is hidden. And when you need some bit of content, you show it.

Comment: Unfortunately the content is not static and will change over time. There is a feed updating a file on the webserver which I intend to use as a sort of pipe.

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is impossible.